# how print the call log when onpressed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-widget

1.I'm try to making a flutter Dialer like calling app

2.How to show the call log in Listview

3.But i tried several ways i known an via the online tutorials it doesn't work

4.How to make call logs flutter

5.It print in Debug Console

6.I want to shows the call log numbers only

7.I also tried call log package but it also doesn't work for me

```
import 'package:callapp/models/logss.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  late final List<Phone> phone;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '*', '0', '#'];
  List icon = [IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.one_k))];
  String display = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Center(
              child: Text(
            display,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
          )),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 310,
              width: 250,
              child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: 12,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      childAspectRatio: 10 / 8,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 2),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                display = display + numbers[index];
                              });
                            },
                            child: Center(child: Text(numbers[index]))));
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 220,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 30,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(display);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.green),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 30,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(display);
                          Text(display);
                          print(display);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.backspace),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (display.length != 0) {
                          setState(() {
                            display = display.substring(0, display.length - 1);
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code of what you have done till now?

Comment: void _callLogs() async {
  Iterable<CallLogEntry> entries = await CallLog.get();
  for (var log in entries) {
  print(log.name);
         }
        }